# How do I turn off my nintendo switch controller, without turning off my console itself?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I'm using a pro controller and I enjoy watching YouTube to fall asleep to. However, I always wake up to dead batteries due to the controller staying active all night.

Is there any way I can keep my Switch on but without having my controller powered on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a small black button (the sync button on a Pro Controller) between the L/R buttons that switches off a controller [as shown here](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/05/video_nintendo_switch_controllers_all_have_a_power_button_hiding_in_plain_sight)

On the Joy Cons, it is in this location:

[image: Arrow pointing to location of button on inner edge of Joy Con]

In most games, switching off the controllers will pause the game until you switch them back on. I'm not sure if this applies to YouTube, though.

Comment: I tested, you don't get the pause if you turn off controllers in YouTube.